# Object Array shows duplicate contents

Tags: javascript, node.js

My NodeJs code that uses request is as follows:

```
var objIdArr    = [obj1, obj2, obj3];
var index = 0;
var result = {};
var resultArr = [];

(function deleteRecur(){

    if (index > objIdArr.length-1) {
    //we are done iterating
        console.log(resultArr); //faulty resulte

    } else
        {       
      request(        //nodejs request module          
          {   
             uri: base_uri + '/' + objIdArr[index],
             method: 'DELETE',
             headers: headers
         },   

           function(error, response, body) {

                var arg = (transMap.get(objType)).res[0];
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    result['vmid'] = objIdArr[index];
                    result["result"] = "Success";
                } else{
                    result['vmid'] = objIdArr[index];
                    result["result"] = "failure";
                    result["detail"] = error;
                } 
                resultArr[index] = result;
                index++;
                deleteRecur();
        });
    }

}());
```

**Expected resultArr**
[{ vmid: 'obj1', result: 'OK' },{ vmid: 'obj2', result: 'OK' },{ vmid: 'obj3', result: 'OK'}].

But console.log prints
[{ vmid: 'obj3', result: 'OK' },{ vmid: 'obj3', result: 'OK' },{ vmid: 'obj3', result: 'OK'}].

Seems like whenever I change **result** elsewhere in the code, its affecting the array resultArr too. How is this possible? Isnt javascript supposed to be pass by value?

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I couldnt think of a better question title. Please feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `var result = {};` inside the function where you use it and push it into `resultArr`. Currently you are overwriting the data each time (the array contains the same object multiple times instead of multiple objects).

Comment: Hey Wain, can you tell me, why the first object in the FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/6b2kM/ already has the number of elements of the array, and the indexes 0-3?

Comment: @dollarVar I don't understand your question

Comment: Yeah, I thought so...ehhmm, look at the picture [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Q7WHV06pYCNkJtSmJMMXNMVkk/edit?usp=sharing). In the first `console.log`ed object is basically the same as in the last objects, and the index in the first object is already at zero until three... :/ Understandable? :D